# Bug: blank locationsNotCovered returned from REST: /tooling/runTestsSynchronous/

Tags: rest-api, tooling-api, platform-bug

Starting a few days ago SFDC sandboxes upgraded to Winter 19 started to return blank **locationsNotCovered** node in /tooling/runTestsSynchronous/ result

For example - a basic call with 1 test class like this:
[image: original call]

Results in this response
[image: raw JSON]

Has anyone else come across this issue? How can this be reported to SFDC? I do not have access to the type of support which allows submitting a case to SFDC.

By the way - the problem is not "workbench" - java client (using WSC library) gets the same response.